# reorder subset of data.table records

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have the following data.table:

```
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table (id=1:10,
                  group=sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, replace=TRUE),
                  val=sample(1:100, 10, replace=TRUE),
                  ltr=sample(letters, 10),
                  col5=sample(100:200, 10)
                  )
setkey(dt, id)
(dt)
#     id group  val  ltr col5
#  1:  1     A   96    x  197
#  2:  2     C   46    r  190
#  3:  3     B   68    p  168
#  4:  4     C   58    w  177
#  5:  5     C   11    o  102
#  6:  6     A   90    v  145
#  7:  7     B   25    k  172
#  8:  8     C    5    l  120
#  9:  9     B   33    f  129
# 10: 10     B   96    c  121
```

now I want to process it with grouping by `group`, and in each group I would need to order records by `val` column and then do some manipulations within each ordered group (for example, add a column with values from `ltr` merged in order):

```
#     id group val ltr letters
#  1   6     A  90   v     v_x
#  2   1     A  96   x     v_x
#  3   7     B  25   k k_f_p_c
#  4   9     B  33   f k_f_p_c
#  5   3     B  68   p k_f_p_c
#  6  10     B  96   c k_f_p_c
#  7   8     C   5   l l_o_r_w
#  8   5     C  11   o l_o_r_w
#  9   2     C  46   r l_o_r_w
#  10  4     C  58   w l_o_r_w
```

(in this example the whole table is ordered but this is not required)

That's how I imagine the code in general:

```
dt1 <- dt[,
          {
            # processing here, reorder somehow
            # ???
            # ...
            list(id=id, ltr=ltr, letters=paste0(ltr,collapse="_"))
          },
          by=group]
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

UPD. As noted in answers, for my example I can simply order by `group` and then by `val`. And if I need to do several different orderings? For example, I want to sort by `col5` and add `col5diff` column which will show the difference of `col5` values:

```
#    id group val ltr col5 letters col5diff
# 1:  6     A  90   v  145     v_x        
# 2:  1     A  96   x  197     v_x       52
# 3: 10     B  96   c  121 k_f_p_c        
# 4:  9     B  33   f  129 k_f_p_c        8
# 5:  3     B  68   p  168 k_f_p_c       47
# 6:  7     B  25   k  172 k_f_p_c       51
# 7:  5     C  11   o  102 l_o_r_w        
# 8:  8     C   5   l  120 l_o_r_w       18
# 9:  4     C  58   w  177 l_o_r_w       75
#10:  2     C  46   r  190 l_o_r_w       88
```

ok, for this example calculations of `letters` and `col5diff` are independent, so I can simply do them consecutively:

```
setkey(dt, "group", "val")
dt[, letters := paste(ltr, collapse="_"), by = group]

setkey(dt, "group", "col5")
dt<-dt[, col5diff:={
  diff <- NA;
  for (i in 2:length(col5)) {diff <- c(diff, col5[i]-col5[1]);}
  diff; # updated to use := instead of list - thanks to comment of @Frank
}, by = group]
```

but I would be also glad to know what to do if I would need to use both of these orderings (in single `{}` block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, this just requires setting the `key` of your `data.table` to `group` and `val`:

```
setkey(dt, "group", "val")
#     id group val ltr col5
#  1:  6     A  90   v  145
#  2:  1     A  96   x  197
#  3:  7     B  25   k  172
#  4:  9     B  33   f  129
#  5:  3     B  68   p  168
#  6: 10     B  96   c  121
#  7:  8     C   5   l  120
#  8:  5     C  11   o  102
#  9:  2     C  46   r  190
# 10:  4     C  58   w  177
```

You see that the values are automatically ordered. Now you can subset by `group`:

```
dt[, letters := paste(ltr, collapse="_"), by = group]
#     id group val ltr col5 letters
#  1:  6     A  90   v  145     v_x
#  2:  1     A  96   x  197     v_x
#  3:  7     B  25   k  172 k_f_p_c
#  4:  9     B  33   f  129 k_f_p_c
#  5:  3     B  68   p  168 k_f_p_c
#  6: 10     B  96   c  121 k_f_p_c
#  7:  8     C   5   l  120 l_o_r_w
#  8:  5     C  11   o  102 l_o_r_w
#  9:  2     C  46   r  190 l_o_r_w
# 10:  4     C  58   w  177 l_o_r_w
```

Comment: that would be perfect solution if I would not need to use several orderings in my `processing` section (i.e. in my real case I would need first to order by one field and then, independently, by another one). I will try to update my example (a bit later) with real data to explain.

Comment: well, I was trying to adapt my real case to show it here, but it turned out to be too complicated, so I gave up :/ But I updated my example - maybe you can advice something about it. In fact, your answer already gives me a solution, but I see that my code is quite ugly for its last 4 lines (see commented line - I don't know if I can use `:=` after `{}` block), so I would be grateful for help in improving it.

Comment: @VasilyA You can use `dt[,a:={...}]` and `dt[,c("a","b","c"):=list({...},{...},{...})]` to create new columns/variables. And the option `,by=group` can be added to either of these.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just looking for `order`

```
dt[, letters:=paste(ltr[order(val)], collapse="_"), by=group]
dt[order(group, val)]
#    id group val ltr col5 letters
# 1:  6     A  90   v  145     v_x
# 2:  1     A  96   x  197     v_x
# 3:  7     B  25   k  172 k_f_p_c
# 4:  9     B  33   f  129 k_f_p_c
# 5:  3     B  68   p  168 k_f_p_c
# 6: 10     B  96   c  121 k_f_p_c
# 7:  8     C   5   l  120 l_o_r_w
# 8:  5     C  11   o  102 l_o_r_w
# 9:  2     C  46   r  190 l_o_r_w
#10:  4     C  58   w  177 l_o_r_w
```

Or, if you do not want to add a column by reference:

```
dt[, list(id, val, ltr, letters=paste(ltr[order(val)], collapse="_")), 
     by=group][order(group, val)]
#    group id val ltr letters
# 1:     A  6  90   v     v_x
# 2:     A  1  96   x     v_x
# 3:     B  7  25   k k_f_p_c
# 4:     B  9  33   f k_f_p_c
# 5:     B  3  68   p k_f_p_c
# 6:     B 10  96   c k_f_p_c
# 7:     C  8   5   l l_o_r_w
# 8:     C  5  11   o l_o_r_w
# 9:     C  2  46   r l_o_r_w
#10:     C  4  58   w l_o_r_w
```

Comment: thanks @GSee, but as I said in P.S., it's only simplified example where the only action in `{}` is `paste` on a single column. In my real data, I need to do many actions with different columns of ordered subset. I will try to expand my example to make it more clear.

Comment: Is this general enough, or too general: `dt[, .SD[order(val)], by=group]`?

Comment: not really :) I will update my example (in few hours - can't do this right now) to show real case.